# Как динамически добавить данные в запрос при отправки формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма со сложными элементами внутри.
К примеру:

```
<form type="post" action="user.py">
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <div id="year">1990</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Как перед отправкой формы достать значение 1990, и добавить его к запросу, к примеру так:

```
query += 'age=' + $('#year').text();
```

И отправить этот запрос как обычную форму. 
Если кто-то не понял, то просто хочу достать данные из сложных элементов и отправить их со всей формой. 
Говорю сразу что ajax не подходит(ограничение ТЗ).

Comment: Ну так добавьте скрытые поля, перед отправкой занесите в скрытые поля данные из дивов и сделайте submit формы..... а вообще непонятно, зачем делать див, если можно сделать любой элемент формы в котором это значение будет лежать

Comment: все сложнее чем просто div, там элементы интерфейса строятся из div'ов, js и css.

Comment: Ну если там правда всё сложно, тогда соберите все данные с тех элементов в `JSON`, положите, опять же, в скрытое поле, а на стороне сервера достаньте из него данные, сделайте `json_decode`  и всё.... стандартные поля будут в `POST` как обычно, а те сложные будут в `POST['json']` допустим

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно чем не угодил ajax?

Современные браузеры(кроме IE9-) поддерживают встроенный объект FormData, который кодирует формы для отправки на сервер.

Можно сделать так, добавить имя формы:

```
<form type="post" action="user.py" name='myform'>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <div id="year">1990</div>
</form>
```

и по клику на кто-вам-угодно выполнить js:

```
  var formData = new FormData(document.forms.myform);
  formData.append("key", "value");

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/user.py");
  xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: Для ajax нужно будет писать обработчик, что не позволяет сделать ТЗ

Comment: Простите, а что у вас user.py если не обработчик?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в форму скрытое поле, с именем `other_fields` к примеру.

```
<input type="hidden" id="other-fields" name="other_fields">
```

При сабмите соберите все данные с тех элементов в `JSON`, положите их в скрытое поле и отправьте форму.

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
  var otherFields = {};    
  otherFields.age = $('#year').text();
  otherFields.email = $('#email').text();
  // ...
  // и так далее 
  $('#other-fields').val(JSON.stringify(otherFields));
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="user.py">
    <input type="hidden" id="other-fields" name="other_fields">
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <div id="year">1990</div>
    <div id="email">199220</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

А на стороне сервера достаньте из него данные, сделайте декодирование данных. 
Например на `php` это будет примерно так:

```
$otherFields = json_decode($_POST['other_fields'], true);
```

Увидим

```
Array
(
    [age] => 1990
    [email] => 199220
)
```

Остальные стандартные поля будут в `POST` как обычно, т.е. 
`$_POST['lastname']` и т.д.

**P.S.** Не забудьте в методе `submit()` проверять данные на пустоту, на валидность и пр. И если не валидно, то `return false;`

**P.P.S.** У формы кстати надо не `type="post"`, а `method="post"`